# Python Modules In Two Locations, Receiving Import Error

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, import

I ran an install of a `requirements.txt` file and I think due to some restricts with the Mac OS some of the requirements appeared to be installed in my local `/Users/***/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages` directory instead of the global python packages directory.

The problem is when I run python in the terminal it will not import anything.  I tried adding the location above to my python path in the .bash_profile file on Mac but didn't see it working at all.

**Two questions:**

1. Is there a command to try and move or re install all the requirments.txt stuff again as global packages vs just to my user account?
2. What can I try to make it work the way it currently is where the
   packages are split between my local account and the root account.

Comment: can you paste your `req.txt` libs, so that i can try doing same and test. and can suggest. also any specific import you are doing and not working?

Comment: `facebook_sdk==2.0.0
    Flask_Bcrypt==0.7.1
    googleads==5.3.0
    gspread==0.2.5
    httplib2==0.9.2
    numpy==1.12.1
    pandas==0.19.2
    pyquery==1.2.11
    requests==2.9.1
    selenium==2.52.0
    SQLAlchemy==1.0.12
    google_api_python_client==1.6.2
    gav4==0.1.2
    pycurl==7.43.0`

Comment: Having an issue importing pycurl.  On Mac 10.12.5

Comment: what is the error.

Comment: `ImportError: No module named pycurl`

Comment: You should use virtualenv. Isolate python runtimes and package installs.

Comment: I understand.  However, is there a way to make Python on the Mac recognize python packages in both locations?  The pythonpath variable doesn't appear to work.